# Running Paraview Benchmarks remotely

Tags: remote-access, paraview

ERROR: In /home/kitware/dashboards/buildbot/paraview-debian6dash-linux-shared-release_opengl2_qt4_superbuild/source-paraview/VTK/Rendering/OpenGL2/vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow.cxx, line 286
vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow (0x529c2b0): bad X server connection. DISPLAY=Aborted

1. I understand that the main reason why it is not running is because it needs to use a window which it cannot create remotely.
2. I am able to run it locally
3. This is a benchmark provided by paraview.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue arises because the process needs access to an X server to create a Window and then an OpenGL context for all the rendering. The default linux binaries shipped by paraview.org use rely on X to provide the context. If your sever is not going to provide X access to your processes (which is not unheard of), then you should build ParaView with either OSMesa support or EGL support and use that build instead. In those builds, ParaView uses non-X dependent methods to create the OpenGL context.

Comment: building from scratch would be the solution to this particular problem as you have stated.